# installing testdisk

Tags: software-installation

Need to install testdisc by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

But it shows me the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     kde-cli-tools : Depends: kde-cli-tools-data (= 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
     libksgrd7 : Depends: libkf5sysguard-data (= 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
     libprocesscore7 : Depends: libkf5sysguard-data (= 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
     libprocessui7 : Depends: libkf5sysguard-data (= 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify
```

a solution).

When trying `apt-get -f install` it says:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first comand is wrong. It should be like this:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install testdisk`

The second command must begin with sudo:
`sudo apt-get -f install`

The message is quite clear: "Are you root?"... Whenever you meet messages like these, check to see if you have permission to acces that resource; root has permission everywhere, and this is what `sudo` does (runs a command as root); or run `sudo su`, input your password, and now you can run commands without `sudo` (i.e. every command will be run as root - NOT RECOMMENDED)

Comment: Thanks did some installing, but then: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libkf5sysguard-data_4%3a5.5.5-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/processui.mo', which is also in package kde-l10n-th 4:4.10.97-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-cli-tools-data_4%3a5.5.5-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking kde-cli-tools-data (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-cli-tools-data_4%3a5.5.5-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb (--unpack):

Comment: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/kmimetypefinder.mo', which is also in package kde-l10n-th 4:4.10.97-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libkf5sysguard-data_4%3a5.5.5-0ubuntu2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-cli-tools-data_4%3a5.5.5-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: And when I try to execute like this: flo@flo-Z68XP-UD3:~$ sudo testdisk-6.13/photorec_static
sudo: testdisk-6.13/photorec_static: command not found.....????